# View javascript source when code is loaded by jQuery ajax in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

My jQuery code downloads some HTML which includes more javascript embedded within that HTML. In Google Chrome I cannot seem to see this downloaded code. Is it possible to view this code so that I can debug it?

Answer (score 1):

Content loaded via AJAX can be viewed inside the "Network" tab (click the XHR sub-tab if necessary).

In some cases you might be able to find the script (and set breakpoints in it) in the "Sources" tab of Chrome developer tools. Click on the "right arrow" icon in upper left corner to show the list of files that were requested by the page.

You can also set an "XHR breakpoint" in the "Sources" tab, if that helps.

Comment: No I looked. Scripts downloaded by jQuery ajax don't show up.

Comment: Start by Inspecting the loaded page CTRL-Shift-I, then you will see the resources tab.

Comment: so what does your page source look like ? The bit that specifies the javascript ?

Comment: @AndroidDev: You're right, they do not show up there. You can still find them in the network tab near the bottom but you cannot debug it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use //# sourceURL=eval/bla inside of your scrtips to allow debugging. This comment has to added at bottom.

```
<script>
var a = 'b';
console.log(a);
//# sourceURL=eval/bla
</script>
```

If this doesn't work you can still ad debug statement.

```
debugger;
```